# Pact Verification: Can i skip a particular providerState

Tags: java, pact, pact-jvm, pact-broker, pact-java

Can I skip a particular provider state at the time of pact verification execution? like in my pact file I have 10 interactions and I want to skip an interaction or a provider state from StateChangeController. I'm using 'au.com.dius.pact.provider' maven plugin for pact verification

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion on an open issue on pact-ruby(https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby/issues/115), this is something that has been talked about but never implemented. From personal experience, having the result of each interaction present in the pact is needed. If any of the interactions is missing, the verification will not be green. For state setup, you can skip the state from state-state_setup mapping. Doing so might cause issues with the interactions verification.